# How to create public php class object inside a another class?

Tags: php, class, object

How to create public php class object inside a another class?. 
I have a class called

> page.php

and also

> Main.php

and

> Content.php

I want to call Main.php and Content.php class inside the page.php class. What is the correct way to do this.
I tried this, but not working :( . Please help.

```
<?php

class Page
{
   public $main;
   public $content;

    function __construct() 
    {
        $main=new Main_Model();
        $content=new Content_Model();
    } 

    public function Menu()
    {
        $load_menu=$content->Load_Menu();
        ...
        ...
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: PHP OOP 101: `$this->main=new Main_Model(); $this->content=new Content_Model();` and `$load_menu=$this->content->Load_Menu();`

Comment: In your constructor, you are setting local variables - you need to use `$this` to show you want to set the instance properties instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only assume you are new to OOP.

But the issue resides within you needing to access the variables from the global scope.
I am also making the assumption that you are using a framework that provides auto-loading and that these classes are actually accessible.

```
class Page
{
    private $main;
    private $content;

    function __construct() 
    {
        $this->main=new Main_Model();
        $This->content=new Content_Model();
    } 

    public function Menu()
    {
        $load_menu=$this->content->Load_Menu();
        ...
        ...
    }

}
```

That should solve everything for you. Also you should define your variables as private unless you plan on exposing them for use in other places as a public interface. And even then there is discussion on using methods to access private variables.

Comment: The `O` (Open/closed principle "software entities … should be open for extension, but closed for modification") of SOLID would recommend `protected` rather than `private`

Comment: I relay appreciate your answer. Yes Im new to OOP. Actually I am developing a my own frame work. Your solution solved my problem. Thanks

Comment: @MarkBaker as a general practice you are correct, but for beginners I always advise to start as closed as possible and only open up what you need to when you need to. Also in this case, this does not seem like a class that would be extended... so why allow for extension?

Answer (score 0):

This should fix you're issue and I've changed/fixed a few other bits like public/private variables etc.  As others have said you're missing the $this-> in your construct()

```
<?php
class Main_Model {
    public function Load_Menu() {
        return "This is the menu function";
    }
}
class Content_Model {
    public function Load_Content() {
        return "This is the main content function";
    }
}

class Page { 
   private $mainmenu;
   private $content;

    function __construct() {
        $this->mainmenu = new Main_Model();
        $this->content = new Content_Model();
    } 

    function Menu() {
        return $this->mainmenu->Load_Menu();
    }

    function Content() {
        return $this->content->Load_Content();
    }

}

$page = new Page();

echo $page->Menu();
echo "<br />";
echo $page->Content();
?>
```

Comment: Thank. problem have solved by using Beyerz answer. Thanks again